# Have a script, want to add a Show / Hide sheet function to it

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function createSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  ss.getRange('Start!H2:H26').getValues().reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
  })
    .forEach(function (sh) {
      if (sh && !ss.getSheetByName(sh)) ss.getSheetByName('Template').copyTo(ss).setName(sh);
    })
}
```

This works when the 'Template' sheet is shown.  If it is hidden, the resulting copied tabs are also hidden.  I want to either show the newly copied tabs, or I want to be able to Show the 'Template', run the script above and then hide the 'Template' tab again.

So, basically, I want the script above with a function to Show 'Template' run script and then hide 'Template'.  I found a script that should have let me Show it and then Hide it.  But I failed...any help would be appreciated!

The script I tried adding is [found here](https://spreadsheet.dev/activate-sheet-in-google-sheets-using-google-apps-script).

Thank you,
Tim

Comment: Try changing: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` to: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Template')`

Comment: It failed with the error:

TypeError: ss.getSheetByName is not a function

I think it failed as I activate the Macro/Script on a different tab/sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to add `.showSheet()` at the end of this line:

```
if (sh && !ss.getSheetByName(sh))
    ss.getSheetByName('Template').copyTo(ss).setName(sh).showSheet(); // <-- here
```

Comment: Thank you, Yuri.  It was successful.  I wish I could upvote you but I don't have enough reputation.  But you're help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As an author of the question you have the privilege to accept answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer It would be nice )